# Trying to identify a connector

Tags: cables

I have a car equipment with a cable that should be plugged into a cigarette lighter (12v).

I'd like to tweak a bit, and connect it at home to a standard 12V power supply.

However, I can't figure if the connector is standard and, if yes, the kind of connector.

Here is a picture of the cable connector, which is plugged into the device:

[image]

Does anyone know how to name this connector (and thus search for buying one)?

Comment: Almost same-looking connectors I had seen in cassette-tape-recorders. Its counterpart contained 2 pins.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused  I think you mean a figure of 8 connector.

Comment: @JImDearden Yes . Black-coloured, with lie-down 8 (when connected), though asymmetric. probably in  some tape recorders  the chord's counterpart contained a switch or such mechanical system to turn-off the battery connection while chord plugged in.

Comment: in above picture, the fingers working as a scale for size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a semi-proprietary connector. It is almost certainly not available as a commodity item. There are MANY similar-looking connectors. Some of them may even mate with that connector. Beware to use something that is not reversable (inverting the polarity which will toast your "car equipment".) Some possible solutions include...

1. If you really want the exact connector, you will have to buy something that includes that connector.  Or you could modify your "car equipment" to have a more standard, commodity connector.
2. You could use your single cord with the "special" connector and make an adapter cable to use a more standard, commodity connector.
3. You could modify your "car equipment" by replacing the oddball connector with a standard, commodity connector.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved my issue using a simpler solution. I bought a simple AC to DC adapter (similar to [Power Converter 110-240V AC to 12V 8A DC Power Adapter Car Cigarette Lighter Socket Power Supply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017NL3K96)).

Using this converter, no need to tweak a non standard connector. I guess it's also far more reliable and less prone to short circuit.

I still keep @Richard's answer as the correct answer, because it's better suited to my original question .